# Configure a service task as an external task in Camunda

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler, bpmn.io

How to configure a service task as an external task in Camunda BPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the [service task documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/bpmn20/tasks/service-task/#external-tasks).

Here is an extract of the documentation to configure an service task as external.

> To declare a Service Task to be handled externally, the attribute `camunda:type` can be set to external and the attribute `camunda:topic` specifies the external task’s topic. 
>   For example, the following XML snippet defines an external Service Task with topic ShipmentProcessing:
>
> ```
> <serviceTask id="anExternalServiceTask"
>    camunda:type="external"
>    camunda:topic="ShipmentProcessing" />
> ```

For more information also read the [external task user guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/)